# Implementation of abstractproperty

Tags: python, python-3.4, metaclass

Variable `self.x` containing some values can only be created in child class `B`.

This variable is used in parent class `A` and to ensure I don't forget implementing it, I use an [`@abstractproperty`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/abc.html?highlight=abstractproperty#abc.abstractproperty).

Additionally, to avoid evaluating `big_method()` unnecessarily multiple times, I store the value in `self.__x` and return that instead.

```
import abc


class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def x(self):
        pass

    def f(self):
        print(self.x)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = None

    def big_method(self):
        # Quite a bit of code here.
        return 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        # When called for the first time, it stores the value and returns it.
        # When called later, the stored value is returned.
        if self.__x:
            pass
        else:
            self.__x = self.big_method()

        return self.__x

inst = B()
inst.f()
```

It works as expected.

However, I am wondering if there is **any real reason** for using an `abstractproperty`, since I can achieve the same result (that is, getting reminded to implement `self.x`) by.. not implementing it at all:

- When visually inspecting the code, `self.x` would be marked with a "warning" by my IDE.
- I would get an `AttributeError` when trying to run the code.
- On top of that I could use a comment to make sure I easily understand why `self.x` is not implemented in `A`.

Also, is there a better way to implement `x` in class `B`, that is, without repeating evaluation of `big_method()` more than once?

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your question, however `class B(A): x = list(range(5))` should do what you want.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini My bad, I shouldn't have oversimplified the way `self.__x` is evaluated. It is actually using some other methods of class B (and another 10 classes between class A and B). I will edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure I have understood, however try this: make `B` inherit from `object` and add a call to `A.register(B)` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Defining `x` to be an abstract property prevents you from writing code like this:

```
class A(metaclass=abc.Metaclass):
    pass

class B(A):
    # Do stuff...

inst = B(A)
inst.x = "foo"
```

Here, nothing prevents you from failing to define `x` as a property in `B`, then setting a value after instantiation. With an abstract property, you at least need a default value of `__set__` in order for `inst.x = "foo"` to work.